# How to add a second dimension column to an aggregated metric

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a SUM metric and a dimension I am grouping by.
I want to display another dimension, and I know for a fact that the values of the second dimension are equal for all corresponding values in the first dimension. (meaning I would get the same results if I group by the first dimension and if I group by the second dimension).
how can I display the second dimension as well?

```
select 
SUM(case
when (eventType like 'Add') then 1 else 0
end) as sum_uploads,
userId
from entry
group by userId
order by sum_uploads desc
```

the desired result would be if I could run something like that (with the addition of the third column):

```
select 
SUM(case
when (eventType like 'Add') then 1 else 0
end) as sum_uploads,
userId, userType
from entry
group by userId
order by sum_uploads desc
```

I don't know exactly what to try.

Comment: Add userType to the GROUP BY.

Comment: Yes, you typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh, looks like your comment is suitable as a formal answer, let's [reduce the amount of unanswered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597).

Comment: @Sander, the comment is now also as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, *except* those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. add the column userType to the `GROUP BY`:

```
select 
    SUM(case when (eventType like 'Add') then 1 else 0 end) as sum_uploads,
    userId, userType
from entry
group by userId, userType
order by sum_uploads desc
```

BTW, instead of `LIKE` without using any wild-cards, I'd do `eventType = 'Add'`.